# Brownian Motion Hitting Times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I am reading through Walsh's Knowing the Odds book and came across this problem.

Let $B_t$ be Brownian motion. Find the probability that $B_t$ hits plus one and then minus one before time one.

I am thinking this has something to do with the reflection principle but I am unsure how to tackle this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let $T$ denote the first hitting time of $1$ by $B$ and $T'$ an independent copy of $T$. Then, by the strong Markov property at time $T$ and by scaling, the probability that $B$ hits $1$ and then $-1$ before time $t$ is $P(T+4T'\leqslant t)$. Note that the distribution of $T$ is known.

Comment: Ahh makes perfect sense, thanks very much!

Comment: @Did Where is the factor $4$ coming from? ($\mathbb{P}(T+4T' \leq t)$)

Comment: @saz From the fact that the time to reach $-1$ starting from $+1$, by invariance of Brownian motion by spatial shift and spatial reversal, is distributed like the time to reach $+2$ starting from $0$, which, by scaling of Brownian motion, is distributed like $4T$.

Comment: @Did Ah, I see. Thanks a lot.